# Object renders only in viewport

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, visibility

What I see in the viewport is correct:
[image]

But one of the canisters is excluded when I render:
[image]

Test renders were working fine and now suddenly this strangeness, regardless of whether I render a single image or via animation. The missing object is enabled for rendering and set to be visible to camera. I don't know what else it could be. It's killing me. Please help.

[*** BLEND FILE ***](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12AkTGE2g3i87Hz1nWquaBYz2eZy9xuz5/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: hello, your link asks for authorization  ;)

Comment: Yikes! Thx moonboots. Should be good now.

Comment: it looks like it's the particle system that makes it invisible, if you remove the particle system you'll see the object again, I'm not sure why...

Comment: Hmmm... I did delete the inflow object after the bake. I wonder if that has something to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Show Emitter` is ticked on the left canister but not on the right canister. Tick it and it will show up.

[image]

Comment: Oh, sheesh. You are the man, Harry. A thousand thank-yous.

Comment: no prob, glad i was able to help! sometimes we lose sight of simple details in a complicated project :)

Comment: wow of course   ;)